# Anyone to explain this ACL schema for me

Tags: schema, joomla1.5, acl

It is joomla schema actually but this really drives me banana as I cannot understand it. Please guys help me interpret the whole thing. I can only understand the jos_users and little part of session. I cannot get what other tables do.
Here is image![image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla 1.5 ACL uses the open-source GACL library. You can find more information from these links.

http://api.joomla.org/phpGACL/gacl.html

http://phpgacl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks, let me check the library itself and I will be back
Thanks for the comment and sorry for late reply

Comment: I was looking at it and I found Latest Version:05-Sep-06 - v3.3.7! Why would Joomla use such non updated Library for so long! Thanks for that though. I will poke to see if I can poke it

Comment: Joomla 1.6 they are using a brand new ACL, which offers more control for the end users, but from a developers stand point is a little more difficult to work with (IMO).